# React-Bootstrap-Table-Next Sort Alphanumeric Strings on Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have a dynamic table that generates 70+ columns in React-Bootstrap-Table-Next. I'm running into a problem trying to sort the columns in alphanumerical order (some columns are numbers and some columns are letters). The data being fed into the columns are all **strings**. I'm using the sortFunc but of course it only sorts columns that are numerical strings. How can I get the sortFunc to sort both?

This is my function I have tried. Checkout the sortFunc.

```
let columns = [];
let headers = Object.keys(this.props.reconDetails[0]); //creating the text for headers
const newColumn = {
   dataField: header,
   text: header,
   sort: true,
   sortFunc: (a, b, order, dataField) => {
      if (order === 'asc') {
          return b - a;
      }
       return a - b;
      };
   columns.push(newColumn);
   this.setState({
     columns
   })
}
```

Bootstrap Table:

```
BootstrapTable
   striped
   headerClasses="tableHeader"
   classes="tableBody"
   wrapperClasses="table-responsive"
   keyField={"Case_Line_Number"}
   data={this.state.RECON_DETAIL}
   columns={this.state.columns}
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here as it explains it well. The author utilized the localeCompare method. http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2019/07/19/The-better-way-to-do-natural-sort-in-JavaScript/

I solved my problem below:

```
sortFunc: (a, b, order, dataField) => {
   if (order === 'asc' || !order) {
       return b.localeCompare(a, navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language, {numeric: true, ignorePunctuation: true});
       }
       return a.localeCompare(b, navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language, {numeric: true, ignorePunctuation: true});
       },
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. I have strings that could be numbers, letters, dates, even raw HTML. And this seems to work for all of them. Cheers!